# How to call a function from powershell script install.ps1 when installing nuget package

Tags: powershell-3.0, nuget-package, nuget-spec

I am trying to automatically call powershell script when install my own nuget package.

My install.ps1 is as below

I want to call a function in functions.ps1 which is in tools\Functions.ps1

Functions.ps1

```
Function Write-HelloWorld($param1 , $param2)
{
    Write-Output "$param1 and $param2"
}
```

Install.ps1

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

. .\Functions.ps1

Write-HelloWorld 1,2
```

I am getting error saying the install.ps1 not able to find the function Write-HelloWorld.

How to call the function Write-HelloWorld in functions.ps1 inside install.ps1?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having

```
..\Functions.ps1
```

you can use

```
. (join-path $toolsPath 'Functions.ps1')
```

Both the `install.ps1` file and the `Functions.ps1` file will need to be in the `tools` folder.